# PDFBox document to InputStream

Tags: java, inputstream, pdfbox

I'm trying to take a `PDDocument` object and pass it to other module as `InputStream` without saving the document to the file system.

Now, I read about `PDStream` and kind of understood the purpose of this. Hence, I tried to do something like this:

```
PDStream stream = new PDStream(document);

InputStream is = stream.createInputStream();
```

But when I try to load that input stream into a `PDDocument`, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error: End-of-File, expected line
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.readLine(BaseParser.java:1111)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseHeader(COSParser.java:1885)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parsePDFHeader(COSParser.java:1868)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:245)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1098)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:995)
    at app.DGDCreator.main(DGDCreator.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:143)
```

Later I discovered that the result file is 0kb in size...

Comment: Why not using a `java.io.Input/OutputStream` and `save(OutputStream out)` and `load(InputStream in)` ?

Comment: Because I don't want to save the document. I want to pass it as a stream of data to another module

Comment: What do you want to do with the document in the other module? Why not just pass the document object?

Comment: Why not save to a BufferedArrayOutputStream and then create a BufferedArrayInputStream from there?

Comment: `new PDStream(document)` does not create a new stream  *containing* the document but instead a new stream  *to use inside the document*. If you really want to stream a pdf from one piece of code to the next without buffering it as a whole, consider using a `PipedInputream`/`PipedOutputStream` construct.

Answer (score 17):

So anyone else searching can have a good answer to this. I ran into this same situation where I didn't want to have to save the file to any machine and just handle the stream itself. I found an answer [here](https://coderanch.com/t/612476/java/PDFBOX-PDDocument-ByteArray) and will repeat it below.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
pdDoc.save(out);
pdDoc.close();
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
```

Comment: This essentially is the same as @AhmetRasitBekar's answer.

Comment: My implementation doesn't require a physical file location to save the file to in order to get it into an input stream. It does everything in memory.

Comment: Your 4 code lines effectively are a subset of his code, they more or less represent the core of his solution, too, the rest of his code may be there to illustrate the use. you might say you isolated the essential code, but that's about it.

Comment: Oh yes, that's right. I guess I missed that. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @mkl this solution might be a subset/essential code, but I am new to the pddocument library and this solution got me what I needed.

Comment: @rhavelka Ok, Eric's answer apparently does have its merits, in particular it concentrates on the actual problem...

Comment: Is this more performant than saving the PDDocument to a file and then reading the file back into an input stream off disk?  This seems like it would all happen in memory, right?

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't understand why you want to do this but, following code will do it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    byte[] file = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(
            "C:\\temp\\a_file.pdf"));

    PDDocument document = null;

    InputStream is = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = null;

    try {
        document = PDDocument.load(file);
        out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        document.save(out);

        byte[] data = out.toByteArray();
        is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);

        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File(
                "C:\\temp\\denemeTEST123.pdf"), IOUtils.toByteArray(is));
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(out);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(document);
    }
}
```

Comment: One use case is writing the document to an HTTP connection. Most server frameworks, such as Spring, expect an InputStream. However, PDFBox only writes the bytes to an OutputStream. So you have to write to the OutputStream and then read it back into an InputStream.